# easy way to maintain a min heap with stl?

Tags: c++, stl, heap, min-heap

for user defined struct, as I understand, it's easy. Just overload the operator <. However, for int/float etc.., do I really need to overload operator < for int?
Here is what I tried:

```
       #include <iostream>
       #include <algorithm>
       #include <vector>
       using namespace std;

       bool comp(const int& a, const int& b)
       {
          return a<b?false:true;
       }

       int main () 
       {
         int myints[] = {10,20,30,5,15};
         vector<int> v(myints,myints+5);
         vector<int>::iterator it;
         make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
         cout << "initial min heap   : " << v.front() << endl;
         for (unsigned i=0; i<v.size(); i++) cout << " " << v[i];
         cout<<endl;

         pop_heap (v.begin(),v.end());
         v.pop_back();
         for (unsigned i=0; i<v.size(); i++) cout << " " << v[i];
         cout<<endl;
       }
```

the results are:

```
        initial min heap   : 5
        5 10 30 20 15
        30 10 15 20
```

now pop_heap, push_heap won't maintain the min-heap correctly? is there any easier way to achieve this?
Thanks!

Edit: 
sorry, I didn't check the manual carefully. yes, passing comp to pop_heap or push_heap should do the trick. However, what do you mean, I should not use an external comparator? If it's not the right way, what's the common way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't need to overload `operator <` for `int` (you can't, actually). If you use an external comparator, you should be passing the same `Comparator comp` to `pop_head` as well.

*** Edit: ***

As ildjarn pointed out, your comparison operator does not implement a strict-weak-ordering relation.

```
a < b ? false : true; --> a >= b
b < a ? true : false; --> a > b
```

Comment: The larger issue is that his comparator is equivalent to `int`'s `operator>=`, which is not a strict-weak-ordering comparator, and thus illegal.

Comment: sorry, I didn't check the manual carefully. yes, passing comp to pop_heap or push_heap should do the trick. However, what do you mean, I should not use an external comparator? If it's not the right way, what's the common way to achieve this?

Comment: @user268451 : You can use an external comparator if you wish, but it must implement a strict-weak-ordering relation, so logic equivalent to `operator>=` is not allowed but logic equivalent to `operator<` or `operator>` is. See this excellent article for more info, authored by one of the very fathers of modern C++: [Order I Say!](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/02/order-i-say/)

Comment: @user268451: I may have gotten it wrong, but doesn't the default `operator<` give you the order you intend?

Comment: @K-ballo:default operator < give you a max-heap, max int on the top; I wanna a min heap, min int on the top; so I think you mean the correct comparator for my case is:  return a>=b?true:false;

Comment: @user268451: No, with = in it is no strict order, I think what you need is `b < a`.

Comment: @user268451 : You should just get rid of your custom comparator altogether and use `std::greater<int>()` instead.

Comment: @ildjarn: You should really put all the information you gave in the form of a complete answer, it would certainly be better than mine.

Comment: @K-ballo : Your answer includes its comments, so your answer is good IMO. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn: thanks for the article link and all your comments. I'm still new to stl and that article seems very difficult for me to understand.

Comment: @K-ballo: could you put the whole and right definition of bool comp function in your answer? I still not getting why return a<b?false:true; not working, but b<a?true:false is right.

Comment: @user268451: suppose `a == b`. Then `a<b?false:true` is true. That's wrong, the comparator is required by 25.3/4 of C++03 to have the property that `!comp(x,x)` for all `x`. However, `b<a?true:false` is false, so that's OK.

Answer (score 33):

Use `std::greater<int>()` as the comparator(to all of `make_heap`, `push_heap`, `pop_heap`). The `()` are important - `std::greater<int>` is a functor class not a function, so you need an instance of it.

Answer (score 23):

The answers are good, so I just wanted to add a small example. Say you have the following array:

```
array<int, 10> A{5,2,8,3,4,1,9,12,0,7};
```

and you want to create a `min heap`. The quickest way to do that is to use `make_heap` algorithm. However, that creates a `max heap` by default. In other words, if you call:

```
make_heap(A.begin(), A.end());
```

`A` becomes a `max heap`. To have a `min heap`, on the other hand, you need to add a comparator but do not need to implement one. Instead call the method as follows:

```
make_heap(A.begin(), A.end(), greater<int>());
```

This call will make your array a `min heap`.

PS: `#include <algorithm>` is necessary to use `std::make_heap`. 
Same operations apply to the `vector` as well.

HTH!