# Heaps in c++ using vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl

How does lastline work?
Will it make max heap or min heap?

```
int myints[] = {10,20,30,5,15};

std::vector<int> v(myints,myints+5);

std::make_heap (v.begin(),v.end());
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the documentation for [`std::make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) ?

Comment: Is it possible to create min heap using make_heap. I saw document but I didnt see ?

Comment: @PrashantGupta: I found a [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681779/easy-way-to-maintain-a-min-heap-with-stl) about a min heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[std::make_heap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) is part of the "heap" functions in the standard library. They all work by using an underlying data store. In the case you gave you are using a `std::vector` as your data store.

Calling `std::make_heap` passing in the range of your data store will heapify its contents, causing the first element to the largest in value and satisfying all requirements for [std::push_heap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) and [std::pop_head](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap).

> How does lastline work ? will it make max heap or min heap?

It makes a max heap within the `std::vector` supplied (v).